# How to make SOAP WSDL request in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xml, soap, wsdl

I have a WSDL script which has the following format

```
<definitions name="ProcessData" targetNamespace="urn:ProcessData">

<message name="CreateAccount">
<part name="firstName" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="lastName" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="emailAddress" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="sendEmail" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="key" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>

<message name="CreateAccountResponse">
<part name="result" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<definitions>
```

How to make SOAP WSDL request in Objective-C and get the resonse ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look: http://ditchnet.org/soapclient/